# What is the fastest way to parse text?

Tags: string, parsing

Say I want to extract the first word (or floating point number) that follows a given string found in some text file (see [How to extract the first word that follows a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549877/how-to-extract-the-first-word-that-follows-a-string)). I know you can do it with perl, or sed, and probably many other ways. I am looking for performance. What is the fastest way to parse?

Comment: what is "performance" here, of what size are the data sets? What performance is expected, how many data do you want to extract? I remember a case where we extracted (lots of) data from 100MB crystallographic data output files - and the extraction process per file was eventually about 1-2 seconds (including file read).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a fixed string, you probably want to search for it using something like Boyer-Moore or Boyer-Moore-Horspool (for the latter, I'd recommend Ray Gardner's implementation). Note that B-M and B-M-H are both **sublinear**. Regular expressions, by contrast, are linear at best<sup>1</sup>, and many implementations (those that use backtracking) are quadratic.

The next step is to ensure you're reading the data into memory as quickly as possible. In reality, this is typically going to be the bottleneck. Unfortunately, to deal well with the bottleneck, you typically have to use some non-portable code. Under Linux, `mmap` tends to be about your best bet, while under Windows you're *usually* better off reading large chunks at a time, and invoking `CreateFile` with the `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING` flag. It's also worth using I/O completion ports (IOCP) to carry out the reading, so you can carry out the searching and the reading in parallel.

<sup>1</sup>In theory it would be possible to write an RE engine that did sublinear searching for the right kinds of patterns -- but if there's any that actually does, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: Why use `FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING`? Won't that disable the read-ahead, causing *worse* throughput?

Comment: It disables the read-ahead, thus the recommendation toward using IOCP (where you can control the readahead explicitly). The problem is that caching pre-supposes that you'll use the same data again soon, but in this case, that's unlikely. At the same time, it can/will flush data from the cache that really does stand a good chance of being used -- and if that data is dirty, flushing it will require writing it out to disk...

Answer (score 1):

As with most similar questions, I would implement your particular case and measure it using a selection of applicable tools.

You *may* find that other factors skew your figures e.g. speed to open/read file etc. and so a technology recommendation would be worthless.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time you will be reading the string from the disk, or even worse, reading it from network, and that is already orders of magnitude slower than any sane way of searching you choose. Having said that, if your string is already in memory, and you know your search term up front, regular expressions (real FSM-based ones, not Perl's) are guaranteed to work in time linear to the input size -- so anything faster is only going to be faster by a constant factor. There is a fast regular expression engine library called re2.

Comment: See my answer -- the "only faster by a constant factor" part isn't necessarily true.

Comment: You are right, if the whole string is already in memory you can be faster. I didn't think about it because most of the time need to read it first, and that is going to be linear at best. Well, unless the string you are looking for is really long, so that you can skip substantial parts of input and not read/download it at all...

Comment: right -- realistically, it probably doesn't mean much, and your primary concentration should be be on fast reading.

Answer (score 0):

I'd bet, if it's really a simple case (no real regular expression involved), C would win (memchr() and friends), otherwise TCL would be a strong contender, followed by Perl (latter requires good crafting skills for regular expression design).

**Addendum**: reading your description again (and the accompanying link), I'd say you should test some tools and compare the results. Can you provide an input file for us (somewhere) and specify the exact problem based on that file?

**Addendum 2 (for Feynman)**:
I saved this site (~44KB, 'sof.dat') and performed a repeated search test 
(as you proposed: "site design /") in Perl. This is the code used:

```
 ...
 use Benchmark qw' timeit timestr ';

{
  open my $fh, '<', 'sof.dat' or die $!;
  undef $/;
  our $data = <$fh>;
  close $fh;

   my $count = 100000;
   my  $t = timeit($count, ' $data =~ m|site design /| ? 1 : 0 '  );
   print "$count loops of code took:", timestr($t),"\n";
}
...
```

With my setup (2,4GHz E6600, Win7, Activeperl), the following timings came out:

> 100000 loops of code took: 1 wallclock secs 
>   ( 1.36 usr +  0.00 sys =  1.36 CPU) @ 73746.31/s (n=100000)

which means, I can find this text in this page about 74 thousand times per second.

If I include the full file processing:

```
use Benchmark qw' timeit timestr ';

{
   my $count = 10000;
   my  $t = timeit($count, q{
                   open my $fh, '<', 'sof.dat' or die $!;
                   undef $/;
                   our $data = <$fh>;
                   close $fh;
                   $data =~ m|site design /| ? 1 : 0
                   } );
   print "$count loops of code took:", timestr($t),"\n";
}
```

we'll get only:

> 10000 loops of code took: 3 wallclock secs ( 1.70 usr +  1.51 sys =  3.21 CPU) @ 3110.42/s (n=10000)

about 3 thousand search/find passes per second.

Regards

rbo

Comment: My project is still in its infancy. I wanted to pick a good method from the start. I do not have any unusually long data files at this point. How would I attach them if I could make some up?

Comment: ok how about this: use the html source file of this page. Find the text following, say "site design /" (no quotes)

Comment: wow. Thanks! So I guess I better write an equivalent program in C, bash, and TCL. I have a bash program, but I just copied the code from a thread from another forum. I really do not know these languages very well (or for TCL and pearl at all). I am trying to automate generating input files for some other software and extracting lines from the output. I think conducting this experiment is beyond me. I just learn the basics and get the rest from google. Thanks for the input.